# Position of @type in JSON object causes error

Tags: json, jaxb, moxy

Given the following class:

```
@XmlSeeAlso({A.class, B.class})
@XmlDiscriminatorNode("@type")
public abstract class Base implements Serializable {
}
```

Let `A` (and analogous `B`) be:

```
@XmlDiscriminatorValue("A")
public class A extends Base {
    private String foo;
    // constructor, getter, setter
}
```

Wrapping a `List<Base>` containing objects of both types will lead to this sample JSON:

```
{
  "list": [
    {
      "@type": "A",
      "bar": 123
    },
    {
      "@type": "A",
      "bar": 789
    },
    {
      "@type": "B",
      "foo": "sddadad"
    },
    {
      "@type": "B",
      "foo": "ttf4eg4gf sd"
    },
    {
      "@type": "A",
      "bar": 465
    }
  ]
}
```

Now to the part where my question kicks in: when the `@type` property is moved off of the "first" position, the unmarshal fails:

```
{
    "bar" : 123,
    "@type" : "A"
}
```

<kbd>`Exception Description: Missing class indicator field from database row [UnmarshalRecordImpl()].`</kbd>

Is this an expected behaviour? Do i have to make sure the `@type` declaration is "first" all the time?

I'm using the EclipseLink 2.5.1.v20130619-ffd088c nightly build.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the `UnmarshallerProperties.JSON_ATTRIBUTE_PREFIX` is specified on the unmarshaller then currently [**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) requries that the keys with the attribute prefix occurs before the keys without.  I have opened the following enhacement request (see link below) that you can use to track our progress on this issue.

- http://bugs.eclipse.org/411501

**Workaround**

This issue only occurs when the `UnmarshallerProperties.JSON_ATTRIBUTE_PREFIX` property is set.  When it is not set MOXy can unmarshal the following without any issues:

```java
{
    "bar" : 123,
    "type" : "A"
}
```